# python pandas break row to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

Need to accomplish the following in PYTHON pandas. Sample source is provided below. Kindly help.

Source:

```
  COLA COLB COLC  COL_GRP_A_1  COL_GRP_A_2  COL_GRP_A_3  COL_GRP_B_1  COL_GRP_B_2  COL_GRP_B_3  COL_GRP_C_1  COL_GRP_C_2  COL_GRP_C_3
0    H    I    J          0.1            1            3            4          2.5            6            2            5            4
```

Expected output:

```
  COLA COLB COLC        GRP  COL_VAL1  COL_VAL2  COL_VAL3
0    H    I    J  COL_GRP_A       0.1       1.0         3
1    H    I    J  COL_GRP_B       4.0       2.5         6
2    H    I    J  COL_GRP_C       2.0       5.0         4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a relatively straightforward application of `pandas.wide_to_long` with a bit of a a twist that tokens in column names should be re-arranged for `wide_to_long` to work as intended

Come up with new names for the relevant columns:

```
grp_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('COL_GRP')]
new_grp_cols = []
for name in grp_cols:
    t = name.split('_') 
    new_name = t[0]+'_' + t[1]+'_' + t[3] + '-' + t[0]+'_' + t[1]+'_' + t[2] 
    new_grp_cols.append(new_name)
# new_grp_cols = [t.split('_')[0]+'_' + t.split('_')[1]+'_' + t.split('_')[3] + '-' + t.split('_')[2] for t in grp_cols]
new_grp_cols
```

They look like this:

```
['COL_GRP_1-COL_GRP_A',
 'COL_GRP_2-COL_GRP_A',
 'COL_GRP_3-COL_GRP_A',
 'COL_GRP_1-COL_GRP_B',
 'COL_GRP_2-COL_GRP_B',
 'COL_GRP_3-COL_GRP_B',
 'COL_GRP_1-COL_GRP_C',
 'COL_GRP_2-COL_GRP_C',
 'COL_GRP_3-COL_GRP_C']
```

Rename the columns:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns = dict(zip(grp_cols,new_grp_cols)))
```

Apply `wide_to_long`

```
df3 = pd.wide_to_long(df2.reset_index(), stubnames = ['COL_GRP_1','COL_GRP_2', 'COL_GRP_3'], i='index', j='GRP', sep = '-', suffix = '\D+').reset_index(level=0, drop = True)
df3
```

output

```
GRP        COLB    COLC    COLA      COL_GRP_1    COL_GRP_2    COL_GRP_3
---------  ------  ------  ------  -----------  -----------  -----------
COL_GRP_A  I       J       H               0.1          1              3
COL_GRP_B  I       J       H               4            2.5            6
COL_GRP_C  I       J       H               2            5              4
```

Comment: Thanks. Informative.